# Create legend on ggplot when combining two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to create a manual legend when plotting two time series as two columns of one dataset on a figure.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=datetime)) + geom_line( aes(y=y1), color = 'red') + geom_line(aes( y=y2),color='blue')
```

I am getting a figure with no legend so far
[image]

I just need to add a legend with names for the colors red and blue like:

[image]

Comment: This gets asked a lot on Stack Overflow, and there are many examples on here if you use the search bar at the top, but I have closed this as a duplicate, since the first answer in the linked duplicate question should give you a working solution. Essentially, you need to add `color = "Y1"` inside the `aes` call in the first geom_line,, and `color = "Y2"` inside the `aes` of the second one. Remove the `color = "red"` and `color = "blue"` from outside the `aes` calls. Then specify the colors by adding `+ scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))` to your plot.

Comment: Although the best way to do it would be to pivot uour data into long format, since then you only need a single `geom_line` layer. The linked duplicate shows how that is done too.